# Unwanted animation appear when init UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a problem when I try to draw a button programmatically using the following codes. But my problem is when the button is called, I always see the button moving from the top left hand corner and move to the coordination which I typed in. May I know how to get ride of the animation that moves my button?

```
go= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[go addTarget:self action:@selector(nextbutton1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[go setFrame:CGRectMake(605, 320, 35, 35)];
go.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[go setAlpha:0.0];
[go setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[go setExclusiveTouch:YES];

[self.view addSubview:go];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0 options:YES animations:^{
  [go setAlpha:1.0];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Thanks

Comment: Code looks fine. Is this the only scope of your `go` button? Try to run without the `animation` and place `alpha = 1.0` from the beginning and see if anything happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably got your animation queues all messed around, causing the button's `frame` to animate. Without seeing your entire source tree, it's tough to say where exactly you have incorrectly managed your animations, but you could use this trickery if you really wanted to:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
[go setFrame:CGRectMake(605, 320, 35, 35)];
[CATransaction commit];
```